# ngSubmit won't submit on mobile browser

Tags: angular-material, angular7, angular-flex-layout

when touching (clicking) the button nothing happens!

works perfect on windows 10 desktop using browsers like Chrome or Firefox but NOT with devices such Samsung Galaxy Note 4(android 6) or Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 (android 8).

here is my code..

```
<form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" [formGroup]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="saveCustomer(customerForm.value)">
    <label for=""><h3>New Customer</h3></label>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName" autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Telephone" formControlName="telephoneNum" autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Cellular" formControlName="cellularNum" autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

here is the code on the component..

```
saveCustomer(newCustomer: Customer) {
    this.customerService.saveCustomer(newCustomer).subscribe(
        customer => console.log(customer),
        err => console.error(err),
        () => this.router.navigate(["/customers"])
    );
}
```

someone else is having this issue?

Comment: [Made a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-byedto) to test this and the form is being submitted just fine on mobile browser. Try putting a `console.log()` or `alert()` before your subscription in `saveCustomer()` to see if the issue is in your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if yo try with property **(click)=""** and remove this `(ngSubmit)="saveCustomer(customerForm.value)"`

Ex:

```
<button (click)="saveCustomer(customerForm.value)" 
 type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking good, just replace this line and it will work:

> Replace this line

```
 (ngSubmit)="saveCustomer(customerForm.value)"
```

> With this line

```
(submit)="saveCustomer(customerForm.value)"
```

This is because angular 2+ working on same JavaScript function or html element methods for one way event binding with just putting **(** any js/Html event **)**

ex: **onclick** can be written as **(click)** in angular.
**onblur** can be written as **(blur)** in angular.

Let me know if you get it.